# Import Forms Module only in AppModule not on LazyLoad Modules

Tags: angular, webpack

Hey guys how do I make my lazeload module reconigze Forms Module importing on appModule??

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lazy-loading-k1tven

I can't import forms on each lazy module or on shared module.

The formsModule is just a example of the problem, i using a 3 pt lib and all my lazy modules use it, but i just want load that lib on the init of application not on all chunks of lazy

Comment: There are console error in your stackblitz

Answer (score 0):

The `FormsModule` includes directives so you cannot make it work if you don't import it in every module that uses it. The only thing that can be used cross-module is the services

Comment: Ok putting on shared module it will work, but will load formsModule on all Lazy Chunks, there is a way to only load formsModule one time?

Comment: No, the only way to load lazy modules is with specific routes. Your `SharedModule` is not bound to a route, but contains shared classes, so you're forced to import it where you want to use it, and thus it is bundled in every chunk that uses it.

Comment: Notice that when you lazily load a module, you don't import it.